# Dot syntax with 'id' properties

Tags: objective-c

Recently i asked question about accessing properties of id object assigned to custom class. Solution is casting or using setter/getter methods.

But, i can't understand one thing, why i can't use dot syntax?

Compare that two lines of code:

1. `myClass.var`
2. `[myClass var]`

Result is identical, and in fact, it similar. But, if u do:

```
id obj = myClass;
```

`obj.var;` // Error - trying to get value

`obj.var = 5;` // Error - trying to set value

Its not real error message, i just want to show you that warnings are appear and it crash a build.

But, if u do:

```
id obj = myClass;
```

`[myClass setVar:5];` // No error - setter

`[myClass var];` // No error - getter

No warning, app work fine.

How this could happen? Yes, i can use casting or getting/setting values like described above, but why dot syntax not work?

Comment: `myClass.var` and `[myClass var]` aren't identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

id is "any kind of object", which means it doesn't have any property named `var` so you can't access it using dot notation, because `var` it's not a member of class `id`.

Now, if you use the 'messaging' pattern `[myClass var]` you are sending a message and since message dispatching in objective-c is a runtime functionality and dynamic typed, it won't complain at compile time, because the compiler doesn't know whether `myClass` responds to the selector var (in this case 'has a property named var') or not until it actually tries to dispatch the message to the object.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks but its not almost clear. Alright, id doesn't have such properties, but i assigned class instance to variable, therefore, it contain reference to that variable, isn't it?

Comment: `id obj = myClass` the only thing you are telling is that the id local variable as to point to that instance of myClass, and that's `id` which means any kind of object. The compiler is checking type conformity from left to right (as it's dynamic typed language), so as far as the compiler is concerned you are messaging id. Unless, as you said early, you typecast.